# localizable.strings - works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios-simulator

I have a problem with my language. I only see the ID_String on my device for each entry defined with `NSLocalizedString`. All text/images etc. set in the storyborad are shown correctly. If I use the  simulator everything is fine!

So, I would like to youse NSLocalizedString - to use the option to translate my app maybe later. At this time my app is in german only.

- I use storybord option. In the options I set the Localization to Germany
- I add a string file to my project, also with the german localization
- all lines in this file looks like "OK_Button" = "OK";

In my project folder there is an de.lproj folder including the storybord, InfoPlist.strings and localizable.strings

The two stings are saved as UTF16. I open these files in TextWrangler and savend them again.

I search since a few days for the reason, but I dont see my problem.
Have anyone an idear whats wrong, or whats missing in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason that something works on the simulator, but not on the device is that Max OS X uses case-insensitive file systems by default, but iOS uses a case-sensitive file system. Check to make sure that your case for the filename is `"Localizable.strings"`.

Comment: I love you! 10.000 KISSES!!! I would like to kick my self... 
RIGHT: "Localizable.strings" FALSE: "localizable.strings" - the "l" saved the problem. oh my goooood so many hous left.... THANKS!

Comment: im using Localizable.strings only, then why it is not working for me on device....? And working fine on simulator

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for the problem could be that there is a `Localizable.strings` file in `Base.lproj` directory. It causes the iPhone to use the Base translation file instead of the correct translation file.

see: [Creating Strings Files for User-Facing Text in Your Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions above don't work for you, the problem may be related to your 'Edit schema' and it's Run Language.  That's why your device opens a different language than it's supposed to.

[Open your Edit Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK4ND.png)

1. Pick the 'Run' card on the left-hand side menu
2. Find the 'Options' tab on the left-hand side and pick 'App Language'
3. Make sure that you picked 'System Language'

Even though my device had installed language supported by my app, my edit schema sent a different one. That's why it opened the English version, which was the default one.